# IPs not blocking with iptables/fail2ban "already banned" messages

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

I am using old iptables v1.4.7 in conjunction with fail2ban. I am however seeing "already banned" messages in the logs and can't figure out why they still reach my server and are not being blocked by the *f2b-ASTERISK* section as below. Do you see any reason why the following wouldn't work at a first glance? I checked other answers but they didn't shed a light. Here is the output:

```
[root@server bin]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
f2b-ASTERISK  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:sip
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:sip STRING match "friendly-scanner" ALGO name bm TO 65535
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:sip STRING match "VaxSIPUserAgent" ALGO name bm TO 65535
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:sip STRING match "VaxIPUserAgent" ALGO name bm TO 65535
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:sip STRING match "sundayddr" ALGO name bm TO 65535
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:sip STRING match "sipsak" ALGO name bm TO 65535
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:sip STRING match "sipvicious" ALGO name bm TO 65535
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:sip STRING match "iWar" ALGO name bm TO 65535
...
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2346 flags:0x17/0x02 limit: avg 1/min burst 3
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2346 flags:0x17/0x02
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 state NEW
DROP       all  -f  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x3F
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x3F/0x00
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 5/sec burst 5
DROP       icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:5060
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:5060
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:4569
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpts:10000:20000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 flags:0x17/0x02 limit: avg 100/sec burst 100
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 flags:0x17/0x02
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:5666

...

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain f2b-ASTERISK (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  ip16.ip-54-37-90.eu  anywhere
DROP       all  --  207.231.108.225      anywhere
...
```

fail2ban.log:

```
2023-04-23 09:50:30,881 fail2ban.actions        [26615]: NOTICE  [asterisk-iptables] 207.231.108.225 already banned
```

It's listed in f2b-ASTERISK when I check the ip:

```
[root@server bin]# iptables -L -n | grep "193.32.162.159"
DROP       all  --  207.231.108.225       0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Are you sure the new bans are still being triggered by traffic on udp:5060, and not by something else?

Comment: Okay! I believe you found the problem, I am now noticing that these IPs all try to connect to another port. So my problem would actually be with the fail2ban configuration...thank you so much for this rapid insight !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your rules, the `f2b-ASTERISK` chain is only used to filter packets on UDP port 5060:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
f2b-ASTERISK  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:sip
```

However, your fail2ban logs do not actually say that the Asterisk ban was triggered by this kind of traffic – it might have been triggered by *something else* (e.g. a different port, or SIP-over-TCP, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that nothing references your chain.
You need to have something like

iptables -I INPUT 1 -j f2b-ASTERISK

This will cause iptables to read these rules.

I would switch to ipset mode in fail2ban so that your iptables rules are not clogged by 1000's of drop rules.

fail2ban will create sets with the same name f2b-ASTERISK

Then you can have something like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m set --match-set f2b-ASTERIK -j DROP
```

Now the list of IP can grow without clogging iptables.

to inspect your list:

```
ipset save f2b-ASTERIK
```

This will list out all ip addresses in said group.